# Dynamically set UIViewController pointer inline - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, casting

I have an iOS app with a for loop that creates, sets-up and adds a custom view controller to my view. The problem is that I need to dynamically set the `UIViewController` object to the correct class, depending on the current loop number. Here is my code:

```
// Loop through the data and setup the switches.
    
for (NSUInteger loop = 0; loop < [switchLabels count]; loop++) {
        
    // Create the view controller object.
    UIViewController *screen;
        
    // Create the custom switch view.
        
    if (loop < 3) {
        screen = [[CustomSwitchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomSwitchView" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        screen = [[CustomTripleSwitchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomTripleSwitchView" bundle:nil];
    }
        
    // Create the custom switch view.
    [screen setPassedInType:switchTypes[loop]];
    [screen setDelegate:self];
    [self addChildViewController:screen];
    [screen.view setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 150), ((UILabel *)switchLabels[loop]).frame.origin.y, 144, 72)];
    [scrollTopView addSubview:screen.view];
    [screen didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [screen setTitles:switchTitles[loop] state:[switchSettings[loop] boolValue]];
}
```

The problem is that some of the above method calls come up with the error:

> No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector....

In order to solve this problem, I need to type cast the object `screen`. However I need to dynamically type cast it, based on the for loop number:

If the loop is less than 3, I need to type cast the object to `CustomSwitchView`, otherwise I need to type cast it to `CustomTripleSwitchView`. How can I do this inline? For example I tried the below code, but it didn't work:

```
(loop < 3 ? (CustomSwitchView *) : (CustomTripleSwitchView *))
```

Comment: If they share some common methods that you're using then you should declare a protocol that they both conform to which requires those methods.  Then you can declare your local variable as `UIViewController<Protocol> *`

Comment: Why not try using respondsToSelector before calling the actual method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this.  Least impact to the existing code would be to distinguish methods as those that apply generically to UIViewControllers and those that are particular to the subclasses.  Invoke the subclass methods on stack variables that are declared as the specific subclass...

```
for (NSUInteger loop = 0; loop < [switchLabels count]; loop++) {

    // Create the view controller object.
    UIViewController *vc;

    // Create the custom switch view.

    if (loop < 3) {
        CustomSwitchView *screen = [[CustomSwitchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomSwitchView" bundle:nil];
        [screen setPassedInType:switchTypes[loop]];
        [screen setDelegate:self];
        [screen setTitles:switchTitles[loop] state:[switchSettings[loop] boolValue]];
        vc = screen;
    } else {
        CustomTripleSwitchView *screen = [[CustomTripleSwitchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomTripleSwitchView" bundle:nil];
        [screen setPassedInType:switchTypes[loop]];
        [screen setDelegate:self];
        [screen setTitles:switchTitles[loop] state:[switchSettings[loop] boolValue]];
        vc = screen;
    }

    // Create the custom switch view.
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [vc.view setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 150), ((UILabel *)switchLabels[loop]).frame.origin.y, 144, 72)];
    [scrollTopView addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

This is an okay solution if we're done encountering this problem in the project.  When you see this sort of thing proliferate, it's time to start thinking: (a) should I define a protocol on each class (as a commenter aptly suggested), or (b) are these really subclasses related to one another, like `CustomTripleSwitchView` is really a subclass of `CustomSwitchView`?